# Select item based on property of related item

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have one table, 'Person' and another, Car, where the relation is one-to-many (one person may have many cars).

How can a write a predicate to get all persons who have a car (any one if they have more) with a certain property?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSString            *str        = @"ANY cars.property == 'value'";
NSPredicate         *predicate  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];
...
```